# Problema con el observer en firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

estoy teniendo un problema en el sistema web que estoy creando con firebase, explico:

Al momento de poner el codigo que te brinda la documentacion para configurar el observer, me sale este error en consola:

[image: Problema]

Cuando voy a la linea 69 del file de javascript, me lleva a lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis links de scripts son los siguientes:

```
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-app.js"></script>  
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.23.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "--",
    authDomain: "--",
    projectId: "--",
    storageBucket: "--",
    messagingSenderId: "--",
    appId: "--",
    measurementId: "--"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
```

Quisiera saber si esto tiene algun tipo de solucion, estoy hace dos dias con lo mismo y no se me ocurre como solucionarlo, pegue otros scripts de firebase y no se soluciona, **y otra de mis dudas es** si el observador me sirve para que cuando el usuario acceda con su cuenta a mi web, esta cuenta permanezca logeada, ya que al refrescar, automaticamente tengo que volver a logearme.

Gracias a todos

Comment: Voy necesitar que pongas más partes del código, como por ejemplo donde estas solicitando los cdns de firebase y en que parte de tu código estas usando el onAuthStateChanged, esta en el mismo html donde enlazas firebase?, estas poniendo los cdns al final del body?

Comment: Los cdns estan al final del body, y el onAuthStateChanged esta en un archivo js enlazado, tengo mas sistemas de firebase hechos en ese archivo javascript y todos funcionan sin problemas, solo ese es el del problema

Comment: el archivo que contiene el onAuthStateChanged los estas invocando debajo de los cdns?

Comment: No, encima de los cdns

Comment: Todo código que use o que dependa de otro código debe de ir debajo de este. Probá cambiando la posición.